# How to remove an extra label in am5 pie chart?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

In a pie chart, I have to show 2 types of data and they are shown, but the extra label came from nowhere. How can I remove it from there?

```
async function SetData(data: InquiryCountInfo) {
  let dataSeries = [{}]
  
  if (data.entityInquiryCount !== 0) {
    dataSeries.push( {title: "Юр.лиц", count: data.entityInquiryCount} )
  }
  if (data.physicInquiryCount !== 0) {
    dataSeries.push( {title: "Физ.лиц", count: data.physicInquiryCount} )
  }

  series.data.setAll(dataSeries);
  series.appear(1000, 100);
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psd4x.png)

Thank you in advance)